# How to make a Kucoin futures order with ccxt in python?

Tags: python, ccxt, kucoin

The following code work binance futures using ccxt.
What is the correct code/configuration for kucoin futures?

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd

binance = ccxt.binance()
binance.options = {'defaultType': 'delivery', 'adjustForTimeDifference': True}

securities = pd.DataFrame(binance.load_markets()).transpose()
print(securities)
```

```
=== OUTPUT ===
               percentage feeSide tierBased   taker   maker  ... inverse         expiry            expiryDatetime active contractSize
BTC/USD              True     get     False  0.0005  0.0001  ...    True           None                      None   True          100
BTCUSD_210924        True     get     False  0.0005  0.0001  ...    True  1632470400000  2021-09-24T08:00:00.000Z   True          100
...
```

Comment: I get the following errors when I substitute "binance = ccxt.kucoin()"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/vscode/kucoin.ccxt.py", line 7, in <module>
    securities = pd.DataFrame(binance.load_markets()).transpose()
defaultVersion = self.safe_string(methodVersions, path, self.options['version'])
KeyError: 'version'

Answer (score 4):

`kucoinfutures` requires you to create an apiKey and secret on futures.kucoin.com that is separate from your apiKey and secret for `kucoin`  that you may have created on kucoin.com. For this reason, kucoinfutures is a separate class from kucoin

---

The equivalent code for kucoinfutures to the code in your question is

```
import ccxt
import pandas as pd
import sys
from pprint import pprint
# import logging
# logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

print('python', sys.version)
print('CCXT Version:', ccxt.__version__)

exchange = ccxt.kucoinfutures({
    'adjustForTimeDifference': True,
    "apiKey": '...',
    "secret": '...',
    'password': 'This is you 6-7 digit trading password',
})
# exchange.verbose = True

securities = pd.DataFrame(exchange.load_markets()).transpose()
pprint(securities)
```

**output**

```
python 3.10.1 (main, Dec  6 2021, 22:25:40) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
CCXT Version: 1.67.1
                   percentage  ...                                               info
BTC/USDT:USDT            True  ...  {'symbol': 'XBTUSDTM', 'rootSymbol': 'USDT', '...
BTC/USD:BTC              True  ...  {'symbol': 'XBTUSDM', 'rootSymbol': 'XBT', 'ty...
ETH/USDT:USDT            True  ...  {'symbol': 'ETHUSDTM', 'rootSymbol': 'USDT', '...
BCH/USDT:USDT            True  ...  {'symbol': 'BCHUSDTM', 'rootSymbol': 'USDT', '...
BSV/USDT:USDT            True  ...  {'symbol': 'BSVUSDTM', 'rootSymbol': 'USDT', '...
...                       ...  ...                                                ...
OMG/USDT:USDT            True  ...  {'symbol': 'OMGUSDTM', 'rootSymbol': 'USDT', '...
LINA/USDT:USDT           True  ...  {'symbol': 'LINAUSDTM', 'rootSymbol': 'USDT', ...
IMX/USDT:USDT            True  ...  {'symbol': 'IMXUSDTM', 'rootSymbol': 'USDT', '...
NFT/USDT:USDT            True  ...  {'symbol': 'NFTUSDTM', 'rootSymbol': 'USDT', '...
BTC/USD:BTC-220325       True  ...  {'symbol': 'XBTMH22', 'rootSymbol': 'XBT', 'ty...

[90 rows x 29 columns]
```

---

if you want to create an order on `kucoinfutures` you can do

```
order_response = exchange.createOrder('ADA/USDT:USDT', 'limit', 'buy', 1, 1, {'leverage': 10})
pprint(order_response)
```

**output**

```
{'amount': None,
 'average': None,
 'clientOrderId': None,
 'cost': None,
 'datetime': None,
 'fee': None,
 'filled': None,
 'id': '39292jdf8392039kldlsjas393020',
 'info': {'code': '200000', 'data': {'orderId': '39292jdf8392039kldlsjas393020'}},
 'lastTradeTimestamp': None,
 'postOnly': None,
 'price': None,
 'remaining': None,
 'side': None,
 'status': None,
 'stopPrice': None,
 'symbol': None,
 'timeInForce': None,
 'timestamp': None,
 'trades': None,
 'type': None}
```